# what is difference between returning return from inside loop and outside loop?

Tags: python

Actually, I am a newbie in python. I have doubt in return in for loop section.
-> if i return inside loop  output is 1 for (for string "abcd").
->  if I return with the same indentation that for is using in code, the output will 4.
Can you please explain this happening?

I have added my problem briefly using the comment in code also.

```
def print_each_letter(word):
   counter = 0   
   for letter in word:
     counter += 1
     return counter      #its returning length 1  why ?
   return counter        # its returning length 4  why?

print_each_letter("abcd")
```

Comment: If you return inside the loop, the loop won't finish.

Comment: why 2 upvotes upvotes for this question ?

Comment: if you return inside the loop, it will exit the loop when the return is encountered. That's why the count is 1 for the return inside for loop

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: you can visualize your code on http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html and find the difference easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `return` inside the loop executes the first time the loop is executed, so this happens:

```
counter = 0
for letter in word:
    #'a'
    counter += 1
    return counter #return counter (1) and terminate function.
```

but if you let the loop run first:

```
counter = 0
for letter in word:
    #'a'
    counter += 1 #1
    #'b'
    counter += 1 #2
    #'c'
    counter += 1 #3
    #'d'
    counter += 1 #4
return counter #return counter (4) and terminate function.
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits the function, and it returns `4` because it's out of the loop, and the loop did all it's operations and added up to `4` (since the length of `abcd` is 4) and returns the value.

Comment: why the return returning value 1.

Comment: @ManvirChoudhary Because `return` only returns once, so the first iteration the value is `1`

Answer (score 1):

According to the python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return):

> return leaves the current function call with the expression list (or
>   None) as return value

The reason for the different return values is that the function exits when `return` is called at the end of the first iteration (hence the value of 1).